# A clarification in Bitwise operator

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

i am trying to read an image and print the particular color name with respect to its RGBA value (always keeping Alpha value constant).Well this can be achieved with a very complex way but i came across this function on the internet it worked really well but i was unable to understand how this works as i am familiar with only bitwise operator operating on 2 operands.

this is the code

```
public block(int r, int g, int b)
{
 color = r << 24 | g << 16 | b << 8 | 0xff
}
```

Can some explain this to me , only thing i could make sense was 0xff hexadecimal is 255 in decimal and an Bitwise OR is taking place.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` is a bitwise shift operation.  So what that code is doing is creating a packed RGBA value that has the first byte of R, second byte of G, third byte of B, and a constant 255 A value.

(24 bits = 3 bytes, 16 bits = 2 bytes, 8 = 1 byte)

Also if this code is passed a negative r/g/b value, it'll do the wrong thing.  It might be more clearly/correctly written as:

((r & 0xff) << 24) | ((g & 0xff) << 16) | ((b & 0xff) << 8) | 0xff

which is to say make sure we only look at bottom 8 bits of r/g/b (0xff is an all 1, 8 bit pattern) and pack them into the right byte positions.

Comment: so what you are trying to tell is that since all the 3 values together accounts to 32 bits of data , the 1st 8 bits stores R value and the next 8 bits stores G value and so on. r<<24 means we are shifting 24 bits to left to get the first 8 bits of r. That clears out some stuff, what i don't get is what do you mean by negative r/g/b and why are you specifying as (r & 0xff)  doesn't java do the type conversion on its own when it parses 0xff ??

Comment: a negative number is represented bit wise as leading 1's in binary, so -1 is actually 0xffffffff.  So when you bit shift it left 16, you'd end up with 0xffff0000.  Which when you bitwise or it with the R value will turn the R value to 255.

Answer (score 5):

The `<<` operator is a [bit-wise shift](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). The following table should help you get the gist:

```
 x  <<  y  ->  base 2 == base 10   explanation
 1      0        1         1       multiply by 2^0 = x1 = shift 0 times
 1      1       10         2       multiply by 2^1 = x2 = shift 1 time
 1      2      100         4       multiply by 2^2 = x4 = shift 2 times
 1      3     1000         8       multiply by 2^3 = x8 = shift 3 times
 3      1      110         6       multiply by 2^1 = x2 = shift 1 time
 5      2    10100        10       multiply by 2^2 = x4 = shift 2 times
```

So, if you have numbers R, G and B which all fit in 8 bits, and you write their bits, you are doing

```
  rrrrrrrr 00000000 00000000 00000000 // R << 24: added 24 zeroes
+          gggggggg 00000000 00000000 // G << 16: added 16 zeroes
+                   bbbbbbbb 00000000 // B <<  8: added 8 zeroes
+                            11111111 // 0xff for "fully opaque"
---------------------------------------
  rrrrrrrr gggggggg bbbbbbbb 11111111 // RGBA8, a 32-bit int
```

Where "+" is equivalent to bitwise "or" when there is no carry and used for the sake of clarity

As Alcanzar notes, you have to be very sure that R, G and B all fit in 8 bits (and, due to internal representation, negative numbers have their highest bit, called the "sign bit", set). Imagine that B were actually larger than 255  - using that formula, its "high" bits would mess up the G and/or R components of the result. If you do not trust your input, you can sanitize each component (R, G and B) with something like

```
x &= 0xff; // guarantees that only the lowest 8 bits of 'x' can be set
```